# file moved with git mv showing up as deleted / added

Tags: git

I have a number of files in a particular directory in my Git repo. I changed all of them to varying degrees, added them, and then moved the files to a new subdirectory via `git mv`. Now when I do `git status` I see this:

```
renamed:    path/file1.ext -> path/to/file1.ext
new file:   path/to/file2.ext
deleted:    path/file2.ext
```

`file2.ext` did have much more substantive changes made to it than `file1.ext` did but still...  why isn't `file2.ext` showing up as being renamed?

It almost seems as if git has some change threshold. If the changes to a file exceed some percentage then don't count it as a renamed file but rather as the old file being deleted and a new file being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. Git doesn't track renames; instead it looks at how file contents change and move from one location to another. If one file disappears and enough of its contents show up under a new name, git displays it as a rename. (This is done on the fly whenever you look at the commit history.)

From [`git diff --help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Mltngt):

> **`-M[<n>]`**
> **`--find-renames[=<n>]`**
>
> Detect renames. If `n` is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, `-M90%` means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed. Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes 0.5, and is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`. The default similarity index is 50%.