How to properly handle Git file moves in Visual Studio 2019 when using cut/paste?
Following this question, when moving files in Visual Studio 2019 via cut/paste, Git doesn't properly track the file movement - it marks the file as deleted in the original location and untracked in the new location.
I've created a cmd batch script to fix this by:

Finding deleted files
Locating their old positions and moving them back
Then using git mv to properly move them to the new location

This seems to be working, but I'm looking for a more proper/integrated solution within Visual Studio.
Question: What's the recommended way to move files in Visual Studio 2019 while maintaining proper Git history?
I'm specifically interested in Visual Studio's built-in features or extensions that might handle this better.

git mv is of no help. It's just a convenience wrapper for git add+git rm, nothing more. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41793437/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+mv+add+delete+move

@phd so it doesn't maintain the history of the file?!

After move/rename it's no longer the file, it's a different file.

@phd sorry for being a git novice, but it clearly shows a different message on git status

Git doesn't track moves/renames, GIt guesses them. Use git log --follow, git diff --find-renames, git status --renames or --find-renames.

@phd I am not sure if I fully understand. Would you be kind to elaborate? It seems like a major part of what my cmd batch file is trying to do can already be done with the existing git options, right?

You script doesn't do anything useful. Git doesn't track moves/renames, GIt detects them. git mv is nothing more than git add+git rm. It's not necessary to use exactly git add+git rm, any equivalent commands in VSC will do. To help Git detects move/renames do not commit move and edit in the same commit. One commit for move, another commit for changes.

@phd after reading this I think I understand a bit. Git tries to find the matching pairs during the staging by checking the file hash first and then content matching (default 50% but can be changed). So it is already way more effective than my simplistic cmd batch script. But nevertheless still nondeterministic and slow.

IMHO the best way is to develop a Visual Studio extension (i.e., VSIX Project) that overrides renames and moves (e.g., cut and paste or drag and drop) with git mv if a Git repository is detected.

@phd could you be kind to take a look at this Powershell script and share your opinion? If this is in the right direction then I can implement the same concept as a VSIX Project to extend Visual Studio rename/move functionality.

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. git mv is not any better than git add+git rm, so what is the purpose? I cannot read Powershell, I'm a Unix user, never worked with w32.

@phd the new PowerShell script uses git filter-repo. Check this post.

Wow! Instead of just moving a file you rewrite the entire history? That a bold move (pun intended)!
